# URL signature expired. How can i solve this issue?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

I picked a link of a video from Instagram and from a "Instagram video downloader site" i took the download link and converted that link into html code and put it in custom html on my WordPress site.
But after few days the video is not playable.